# Spring integration: receive messages from multiple JMS destinations

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using java DSL to configure my channel adapters. The thing I want to achieve can be described with the following piece of code:

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(mqCacheConnectionFactory)
                        .configureListenerContainer(container -> container.sessionTransacted(transacted))
                        .destinations(inputDestination1, inputDestination2) // missing method
                        .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                        .id(channelName)
                        .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                )
                .channel(commonChannel)
                .get();
```

So I would like to have `messageDriverChannelAdapter` that would be capable of receiving from multiple JMS destinations. Is it achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

The Spring Integration JMS support is fully based on the Spring JMS foundation. And its `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` provides ability to consume only one `destination`. Therefore `Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter()` doesn't provide an option to configure several destinations to listen to.

Only option you have is configure several `Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter()`s. What is good with Spring Integration that you can output them all to the same `MessageChannel` and you won't have so much copy/paste hell.